# JavaDoc: @link to MyClass.class

Tags: java, javadoc

Is there correct JavaDoc syntax for `{@link Foo.class}`? Neither this, nor `{@link Foo#class}` works. Or is this not possible?

Let me expand a bit:

I have a function `registerException(Class<? extends Exception> exceptionClass)` that get's called with things like `registerException(IOException.class)` and started writing the following JavaDoc for it:

```
/**
 * Registers a new {@link Class Class&lt;? extends Exception&gt;}
 * (e.g. <code>IOException.class</code>} that can be flattened by this handler.
 * 
 * @param exceptionClass - the exception class
 */
```

and I was thinking whether I could place a `{@link ...}` around `IOException.class`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to link to? Where would you want the link to go? It would help if you could give us more context.

Comment: Did you tried this {@link Foo.class}?

Comment: @phil652 Yep, Eclipse shows "JavaDoc: Invalid reference". (The fact that I had written {@Link ...} with an upper-case L was actually a typo...)

Comment: To reference the class IOException, you should use {@link IOException} (without the .class).  I don't know that there's a way to reference the value IOException.class as an example value.

Comment: @DonRoby D'Oh!!! Of course! What was I thinking??? Where else should it link to, other than the class... Sorry... So, I guess the answer is `{@link Foo Foo.class}`, i.e. linking to `Foo`, but providing Foo.class as the text-label for the link...

Comment: @DonRoby (I had just typed this comment as a response to your answer and was about to click "accept". Why did you change your answer to a comment???) :)

Comment: Didn't feel it was very complete.  Perhaps I'll undelete it.  Not a biggie.

Comment: @DonRoby :) I think it was spot on. Not much more to say than that.

Comment: Actually, your note that you can add the text value sort of finishes it.  I've undeleted, added that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The .class is not needed (and apparently doesn't work).

As noted in a comment, 
{@link IOException IOException.class} should create a link with an appropriate text label.

Comment: D'Oh!!! Of course! What was I thinking??? Where else should it link to, other than the class... Sorry... So, I guess the answer is `{@link Foo Foo.class}`, i.e. linking to `Foo`, but providing "Foo.class" as the text-label for the link...